# Understanding ffmpeg re parameter

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

I was reading about the `-re` option in `ffmpeg` .
What they have mentioned is

> From the [docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)
>
> `-re (input)`
>
> Read input at the native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab device, or live input stream (e.g. when reading from a file). **Should not be used with actual grab devices or live input streams (where it can cause packet loss)**. By default ffmpeg attempts to read the input(s) as fast as possible. This option will slow down the reading of the input(s) to the native frame rate of the input(s). **It is useful for real-time output (e.g. live streaming).**

My doubt is basically the part of the above description that I highlighted. It is suggested to not use the option during live input streams but in the end, it is suggested to use it in real-time output.

Considering a situation where both the input and output are in `rtmp` format, should I use it or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use it. It's useful for *real-time output* when ffmpeg is able to process a source at a speed faster than real-time. In that scenario, ffmpeg may send output at that faster rate and the receiver may not be able to or want to buffer and queue its input.

Answer (score 6):

It (`-re`) is suitable for streaming from offline files and reads them with its native speed (i.e. 25 fps); otherwise, FFmpeg may output hundreds of frames per second and this may cause problems.